# installing TorchGeo on Windows

Tags: pytorch, gis, geo, torchvision

after experimenting with [TorchGeo](https://torchgeo.readthedocs.io) on Colab notebooks need to move to Windows environment for more advanced development.
Tried installing as in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/torchgeo and also as the instructions in https://torchgeo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html for creating custom conda environment (hanging for hours on conda env create --file environment.yml).

would be happy to get a reference on a working windows installation.

thanks!

Comment: So, the problem is that conda takes a very long time?